# Determine LED with built in driver?

Tags: led, led-driver

I am looking for a LED that I can use on my first underwater ROV so that I have enough light to record video under water. I am using a 12V battery so I am looking for a bright LED chip around 9-12V / around 400 lumens.

I am trying to figure out whether LEDs need a separate driver or whether they have a built in driver. I have a hard time figuring this out. What are the things to look for?

for example, I've read that there are different technologies like SMB, Cree, COB. Do any of these "by definition" include the LED driver?

Or is it regardless of the LED, and do I *always* need a separate driver for these small LED chips?

Comment: If it looks like they don't have a built-in driver, they don't have a built in driver. Which they won't unless it is an end-user product like an LED lamp. At least you have plenty of cooling in your application

Comment: You do not "need" a driver.   A simple resistor will work.   You need to ensure the current through the LED doesn't get so high the LED melts.   A driver will let you set this to a specific value and will be more efficient.  The resistor will drop some amount of power...maybe 20-30% of total LED power.  The brightness of the LED will change with battery voltage.   With a good driver the efficiency might become 90-95%.   In an ROV application efficiency may be very important to you.

Comment: Ah that's very helpful!

Comment: You may consider the Samsung SPHWHTL3D50CE4TMQF for the LED. It's 2 watts and 370 lumens. They're current $1.80 ea from https://au.element14.com/samsung/sphwhtl3d50ce4tmqf/led-hb-white-4000k-370lm-3535/dp/3003214 and out of stock(at $0.406 ea) at digikey: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/samsung-semiconductor-inc/SPHWHTL3D50CE4TMQF/7560589

Comment: I've never seen a  DC-fed LED module of any sort that includes it's own driver. That's very common in AC, we call them "bulbs", but not DC. It's either going to be setup for a specific voltage using built-in resistors (ala LED strip, USB lamps) or be current-operated (SMD, COB, CREE) and need a driver or matched external resistor (if your voltage is stable). A cheap buck+boost DC-DC converter with CC can convert your battery voltage to a constant current for one of the latter categories of LEDs.

Comment: @dandavis thanks for the help. So if I would go for a COB LED (https://nl.rs-online.com/web/p/cob-leds/8847497) which takes 9V, should I take extra care to guarantee both a stable voltage *and* current? Is a buck+boost converter comparable to a voltage regulator? Last question, where does CC stand for in this context?

Comment: Because you need decently high power LED's and are no doubt running off batteries, I would strongly recommend using high power LED's, underpowering them(running them below rated power improves efficiency) and using an efficient current control driver.  Using resistors with high power LEDs wastes a *ton* of power.  If your battery voltage is similar enough to your LED voltage, you can also get decent results with the ubiquitous AMC7135 low drop out current regulator.  Disadvantage is you have to work in increments of 350mA, which makes it trickier to underpower LEDs by just the right amount.

Comment: You should try to figure out whether you want a single point light source or more of a flood.  If you need close to single point, a COB might be the way to go, but for best efficiency (400 lumens isn't enough to *necessitate* a cob) and ease of construction I'd recommend maybe 4 XP-G3 LED(Very efficient if 4 are sharing a 400 lumen load) or similar on star MCPCB(heat sink boards)s mounted a reasonable distance from eachother on heat sinks that contact water.  If you really want to keep it simple, you could consider existing standardized flashlight parts.

Comment: On the other hand, are you sure 400 lumens is enough?  If it's for photography do you need high CRI or do you need to compensate for the color of the water in any way?  All relevant questions before you try to select LEDs.

Comment: @KH thanks for all the insights. I googled a bit and indeed, 400 lumens seems to be rather low for underwater lighting. I thought (wrong) "4-6 times the amount of light of a smartphone would be nice". I guess I have to play around with the amount of LEDs.

Comment: Note that most high power LEDs have a wide range of operation, most efficient at the low end.  XP-G3s for example, are rated from 350mA all the way up to 2A for some colors(with enough cooling) and can operate below 350mA as well.  If you build more LEDs than you think you need, make sure they're well cooled, and use a dimmer(magnetics can probably be used to build a slider or knob into a sealed casing without penetrating it with a moving part), you should be able to produce a range from not enough light to way more than you need.

Comment: You'll probably need to do a lot of research and one of your biggest challenges is driving them, so if you don't want to get neck deep in electronics, I'd suggest doing some research on easy to use dimmable current controlled power LED drivers like the buckpuck or boostpuck(by Luxeon iirc).  Your options there will determine your options for LED and battery voltages.  Look at datasheets for any component you're checking out, and for drivers/regulators in particular, look for an efficiency graph.  Some types of regulator only get best efficiency when they're close to rated current.

Comment: Once you have an idea how many LEDs you want to go with, you'll have an idea of how big a heat sink you need.  Ideally you want the "fins" of whatever heatsink you use exposed to the water.  Saltwater might be a factor, so you might need to get your heat sink powder coated.  Depending on how many LEDs you have and your budget, you might want an extruded aluminum block, or to recycle a CPU heat sink(obsolete aluminum ones can be bought sometimes cheaper than extruded aluminum in clearance sales and this is also probably the only "cheap" way to obtain heat pipes.)

Comment: This part is entirely an assumption, but you should be aware that CRI or color rendering index is the term used to describe the quality of the light as percieved by the human eye(above water) over the range of colors you can see.  With low CRI lights you can get higher lumens per watt or cheaper LEDs, but you probably don't want to look at anything below 80 CRI and might want 90 CRI.  The search term to find powerful LEDs already mounted to aluminum boards is "*nameofLED* MCPCB"(metal core pcb)

Answer (score 1):

As a shortcut solution, (from a personal experience), it is much better to buy a driver integrated in the LED with it, in my ROV I used a LED that's designed for Motorcycles, it'll probably take some time to find it on the internet or at some vehicle-parts shops but it's powerful and you can use as many as you want.